# How to add subtitles to a QuickTime movie

Tags: c#, quicktime, subtitle

I'm using the AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl QuickTime C# COM component to display video in my software. I would like to add subtitle to the video.

I know that quicktime file can embed subtitle using the following string format:

```
{QTtext}{font:Arial}{plain}{size:12}{textColor: 65535, 65535, 65535}{backColor: 0, 0, 0}  
{justify:left}{timeScale:15}{width:587}{height:33}{timeStamps:absolute}{language:0}
{textEncoding:256}

[0:00:00.10]
I said hello, Dolly,

[0:00:03.10]
Well, hello, Dolly

[0:00:06.20]
It's so nice to have you back where you belong

...
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to found any information of how add this text track to the movie programaticaly...

I tried another solution consisting of adding transparent `System.Windows.Form.Label` above the `AxQtControl` but the transparency doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: The answer might be somewhere [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/213420749/QuickTime-for-NET-and-COM-Developers-QuickTime-Developer-Series).

Comment: In fact I have the printed version of this book and the information is lacking

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to open those files into quicktime player (or any quicktime playback gadget) and it would become a text track automagically. (Just as importing an mp3 file becomes an audio track). Have you tried that?

Once it's a movie track, you add it like any other.

Comment: "you add it like any other" how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that (sorry for VB):

```
With AxQTControl2.Movie 
Dim trkSubtitle As QTTrack = .Tracks(.Tracks.Count) 
If Not trkSubtitle Is Nothing Then 
    trkSubtitle.top = .Height - trkSubtitle.Height
    trkSubtitle.TransferMode = QTTransferModesEnum.qtTransferModeBlend 
    trkSubtitle.OperationColor = "32768, 32768, 32768" 
    trkSubtitle.HighQualityMode = True 
End If 
.Time = 0 
.SelectionDuration = 0
End
```

Comment: I will try to add that but I don't have `AxQTControl2` only `AxQTControl`

Comment: is AXQTControl2 a variable name or a type? the common rule is to start variable name with a lower case letter

Comment: The following code doesn't add any text data to the track.